# Android, получение координат в фоновом режиме чаще чем раз в 15 минут

Tags: android, background

Пишу учебное приложение, которое получает GPS координаты, сохраняет их в Firestore и по запросу выводит трек за определённую дату на гугл карту. При открытом приложении всё работает нормально, я получаю координаты раз в 10 минут, или при изменении местоположения на 10 метров, но необходимо также, чтобы программа могла собирать и сохранять координаты в фоне.
Для получения координат в фоне я использую WorkManager, однако он не позволяет получать координаты в фоне чаще, чем раз в 15 минут. Есть возможность обойти это ограничение? или возможно мне нужно использовать другой инструмент? Я читал про AlarmManager, но написано что в новых версиях Андроид система сама будет решать, запускать ей этот Аларм или нет.
Спасибо.

Comment: С чего вы взяли что именно WorkManager не позволяет получать координаты в фоне чаще, чем раз в 15 минут. Возможно вы неправильно задали setInitialDelay или не вызываете его в конце ворка (если это OneTimeWorkRequest). Без кода трудно понять в чем проблема

Comment: Я прочитал об этом в документации и позже, когда свернул приложение, в логах появилось сообщение о том, что я установил время повтора работы меньше, чем минимально возможное значение в 15 мин. Сейчас не могу найти где именно я это прочитал, код выложу чуть позже, спасибо.

Comment: Рискну предположить, что никак. Гугл потратили годы на то, чтобы лишить приложения возможности постоянно делать в фоне энергозатратные операции. Плюс постоянные подвижке в защите данных пользователей от всех, кроме самого гугла. Закрытие возможности записывать разговоры тому в пример. Даже если сейчас сделать то что вы хотите реально, гугл усиленно будут вставлять палки в колеса вашему трекеру, так что я бы сразу начал искать вариант ближе к парадигме гугла. Может сможете экстраполировать точки, получаемые раз в 15 минут, во что-то похожее на маршрут, или вытащить маршруты из гугл-сервисов

Comment: Нашёл решение: https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates?hl=ru В самом низу ссылка: https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/432d3b72b8c058f220416958b444274ddd186abd/LocationUpdatesPendingIntent По этой ссылке есть куча примеров, конкретно для моей задачи подошёл LocationUpdatesPendingIntent - получаю координаты при помощи FusedLocationProviderClient и затем ловлю их с помощью BroadcastReceiver даже когда приложение не на переднем плане (если приложение закрыто, этот пример работать не будет, но такой задачи и не было.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение: https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates?hl=ru
В самом низу ссылка: https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/432d3b72b8c058f220416958b444274ddd186abd/LocationUpdatesPendingIntent
По этой ссылке есть куча примеров, конкретно для моей задачи подошёл LocationUpdatesPendingIntent - получаю координаты при помощи FusedLocationProviderClient и затем ловлю их с помощью BroadcastReceiver даже когда приложение не на переднем плане, если приложение закрыто, этот пример работать не будет, но такой задачи и не было.